# LINQ to remove elements from one collection that don't match elements in another collection based on a field

Tags: c#, linq, collections

I have 2 Lists of different objects eg List and List.  I want to remove all objects in first list whos value of a field doesn't match on a value of a field in the second list.
Eg I want to remove all Type1 objects from the first list whos Type1.name (string) member doesnt match a Type2.id (string) member in the second list.
Is this possible with LINQ ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

LINQ isn't about modifying *existing* collections - it's about running queries. If you need to change a list in place, you might want something like:

```
HashSet<string> ids = new HashSet<string>(list2.Select(x => x.Id));
list1.RemoveAll(x => !ids.Contains(x.Name));
```

In "normal" LINQ you could do this with:

```
// I'm assuming no duplicate IDs in list2 
var query = (from x in list1
             join y in list2 on x.Name equals y.Id
             select x).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use lambda:

```
var query = (list1.Join(list2, x => x.Name, y => y.Id, (x, y) => x)).ToList();
```

or

```
var query = (Enumerable.Join(list1, list2, x => x.Name, y => y.Id, (x, y) => x)).ToList();
```